# Remote (REST) API for system administration

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, http, route, tc

I've spent a few hours looking for a FOSS or commercial product to solve my problem, with no success.

In the context of a big C++ code-base I was assigned the task to provide some automatic mechanisms to configure a remote linux server (running Ubuntu 14.04 server edition) in multiple different ways.

So far, we only needed to be able to remotely configure the firewall rules and I found a github based project (RFW - remote firewall) which I cloned and customized according to our needs (it's a very simple REST interface to the `iptables` command which I may interact with through http c++ libraries).

Now we are about to introduce a few features which would require an equivalent work to interact with both the `route` and the `tc` command, to configure some specific routing rules and the corresponding quality of service.

Is anyone aware of a software which would allow me to perform such operations through an HTTP/REST API?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a side note, you should definitely have a backup plan if you change routing and firewall rules remotely.  Even if you're very careful, something might cause you to lose access to the machine.

Comment: Thanks @JuliePelletier for your point. We operate in an environment which can take this connection for granted: it's a strongly redundant local area network. In case that connection goes down, there would be far worse problems at the same time.